# R - Replace values in multiple fields when conditions are met

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below:

```
 field1  field2  field3
   x     1      2
   y     3      4
   x     na     na
```

My goal is to replace all the values in field2 to A and field3 to B when field1 ='x'. I wrote two lines to do this and want to see if there is a way to do this in one line.

```
df$field2[df$field1=='x'] <- 'A'

df$field3[df$field1=='x'] <- 'B'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base

```
df <- data.frame(field1 = c("x", "y", "x"),
                 field2 = c(1, 3, NA),
                 field3 = c(2, 4, NA))

df[df$field1 == "x", c("field2", "field3")] <- list("A", "B")
```

data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(field1 = c("x", "y", "x"),
                 field2 = c(1, 3, NA_character_),
                 field3 = c(2, 4, NA_character_))

dt[field1 == "x", `:=`(field2 = "A", field3 = "B")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(field2 = case_when(field1 == "x" ~ "A", 
                            TRUE ~ field2),
         field3 = case_when(field1 == "x" ~ "B", 
                            TRUE ~ field3))
```

Not one line, but clean.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `matrix` for replacement.

```
df1[df1$field1 == "x", 2:3] <- t(matrix(c("A", "B"), 2, 2))
df1
#   field1 field2 field3
# 1      x      A      B
# 2      y      3      4
# 3      x      A      B
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(field1 = c("x", "y", "x"), field2 = c("A", "3", 
"A"), field3 = c("B", "4", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```